# Responsive versions not working although viewport tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i'm working on a website where the responsive versions are not working (both on browser and on device). The mobile version is actually getting the queries but some issues are still occurring.

And yes i have already used the viewport tag as it follows:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Here's the link of the website: http://www.zetasportitalia.com/

Comment: seems to be working

Comment: everything looks ok for me! What is the exact problem?

Comment: Try removing browser cache

Comment: For some weird reasons now it seems to work...while on browser works totally correct, on the actual devices i still have some minor issues though. Thanks guys